# Search Form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, will-paginate

I'm trying to add a search form for my list of users which was authenticated by Devise. I am also using Will Paginate gem and have watched the video in [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/51-will-paginate?autoplay=true). The following are the contents of some of my files:

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/list'
  root 'static_pages#home'

  devise_for :users

  devise_scope :user do
    get  '/signup',    to: 'devise/registrations#new'
    get  '/login',   to: 'devise/sessions#new'
    get  '/signout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end

  get 'static_pages/about'
  get 'static_pages/faqs'
  get 'static_pages/contact'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

user_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def list
    @users = User.search(params[:search], params[:page])
  end
end
```

list.html.erb:

```
<h1>List of Users</h1>
  <% form_tag users_list_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    </p>
  <% end %>

  <% for user in @users  %>
    <p>ID: <%= user.id %></p>    
    <p>Username: <%= user.username %></p>    
    <p>Email: <%= user.email %></p>    
    <p>Name: <%= user.name %></p>    
  <% end %>   

  <%= will_paginate @users %>
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :authentication_keys => [:login]


  def self.search(search, page)
      paginate :per_page => 5, :page => page,
               :conditions => ['name like ?', "%#{search}%"],
               :order => 'name'
  end

  def login=(login)
      @login = login
  end
  def login
      @login || self.username || self.email
  end

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
      conditions = warden_conditions.dup
      if login = conditions.delete(:login)
          where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
      else
          if conditions[:username].nil?
              where(conditions).first
          else
              where(username: conditions[:username]).first
          end
      end
  end
end
```

However, I am getting an error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditions are part of query not pagination. They should be in [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) methods as well as order:

```
def self.search(search, page)
  where(['name like ?', "%#{search}%"])
  .paginate(per_page: 5, page: page),
  .order('name')
end
```